# Want to restrict a user from starting notebook instance in sagemaker studios

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker-studio

i am exploring sagemaker studios and trying to figure out a way to prevent a particular user from starting sagemaker notebook instance. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just ensure the user IAM permissions do not include `sagemaker:StartNotebookInstance`, or explicitly deny this permission.

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/api-permissions-reference.html) on Sagemaker-related permissions.